# EF - Automatic update of a field when another is updating (Last Update Date)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Lets say I have the following objects

```
public class Car{
     public int id;
     public string name;
     public string color;
     publid DateTime LastUpdateDate;
}

public class CarPart{
     public int id;
     public string name;
     public string color;
}
```

Whenever someone updates any field, I want the LastUpdateDate field to be updated.
My worst design is to write something like the following

```
public void setName(string name){
    this.name=name;
    this.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.now;
}
```

a. the classes are auto generated and I would have to maintain a partial.
b. too coupled.

1. Is there a recommended framework/design pattern I can use to solve this?
2. Does Entityframework has a feature that handle this requirement.

notice: I am looking for something that will handle it for a field change in the object(Car) and its multivalue (CarPart) objects
Thanks.

Comment: Not giving an answer here .. But keeping date at your c# will give the server dates .. wouldn't it be better to use GetDate() at Db side to keep  consistency for multiple servers

Comment: I think it is a very good comment.
BTW: Shouldn't it be  done on a table trigger ?

Comment: Yes that would be most apt I feel... just that we always preferred to have any dates on the Db side rather than servers until unless we needed server side dates but those would be in xml so not really representation of any columns. Thanks

Comment: I know this thread is almost 1 yr old, but I recommend using UTC dates when storing these things...so it doesn't matter which server provides the date.  Also, if using SQL Server's date function, theres a GetUtcDate() equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Most people tend to override the Context's `SaveChanges()` method for auditing.

First create an `IAuditable` interface and apply it on all Entities you want to audit:

```
public interface IAuditable
{
    public DateTime? LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your `Context`:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
      var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                 .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified);

      foreach (var entry in entries)
      {
            var auditableEntity = entry.Entity as IAuditable;

            if (auditableEntity  != null)
                auditableEntity.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
      }

      return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Also, take a look at

1. [AuditDbContext](http://auditdbcontext.codeplex.com/)
2. [Entity Framework 6 Interception](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Interception) (new feature).

Comment: Correct me wrong .. but isn't this explicitly setting the date? .. Is there any change in the design

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad, yes it does explicitly set the date. as per your comment above, relying on the DB `GetDate()` is indeed better but in depends on each project's requirements.